# Error configuring mongo and neo4j with spring boot 1.5.7

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I am using MongoDb and Neo4j in my Spring Boot Application. I have recently updated by Spring Boot Gradle Plugin from 1.2.6 to 1.5.7.

I am having two config files one for mongo and other for neo4j. After updating the version of spring boot I found that `@EnableMongoRepositories` and `@EnableNeo4jRepositories` are showing following errors in their respective config files:

> No constructor with 1 argument defined in class
>   'org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean'
>
> No constructor with 1 argument defined in class
>   'org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.GraphRepositoryFactoryBean'

I am having following annotations in neo4j config:

> @Configuration
>   @EnableNeo4jRepositories("<packagename>.neo4j.repository")
>   @EnableTransactionManagement
>   public class DatabaseConfigurationNeo4j
>   extends Neo4jConfiguration 
> {
>  ... 
> }

and following annotations in mongo config:

> @Configuration 
> @Profile("!" + Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_CLOUD)
>   @EnableMongoRepositories("<packagename>.repository")
>   @Import(value = MongoAutoConfiguration.class)
>   @EnableMongoAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "springSecurityAuditorAware")
>   public class DatabaseConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration
>   {
>  ...
>  }

If I remove these @EnableRepositories line from the files, these errors are removed but when I run it, the repositories bean are not creating. I think these lines are necessary but dont know how to remove this error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updating spring-neo4j to 4.2.8 (not 5.0.0 as neo4j 5.0.0 will work with spring-boot 2.0 M and above) and spring-mongo to 1.10.6 solved the configuration issues.